# Build on jenkins and sonatype maven giving me a bad request

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus3

When I try to build a maven artifact with Jenkins the build output says the following:

[image: Jenkins build output]

I had already a bunch of successful builds on version 1.0.
I'm using CentOS and Nexus 3 OSS.

Comment: See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825374/3353717 for what can cause 400s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 Bad Request will be returned if you attempt to:

- Deploy a snapshot artifact (or version) ending in -SNAPSHOT to a release repository
- Deploy a release artifact (version not ending in -SNAPSHOT) to a snapshot repository

Also check: [Error when deploying an artifact in Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649486/error-when-deploying-an-artifact-in-nexus)

Comment: Yeah, I removed the -SNAPSHOT and the first build it was successful but the next ones weren't.

Comment: @tommyduarte That's what I'd expect for a release repository (don't allow a specific release number to be over-written), whereas snapshot builds will typically allow a repeated builds with the same version number.
If you are trying to build snapshots, then check your configuration for <snapshotRepository> in your pom or entry in settings.xml.
The following post has a lot of info that you might find useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898703/how-to-configure-pom-xml-file-to-use-nexus-repository-manager